# How can i use CCBezier in CCRepeatForever?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to make zigzag on my game. I am using CCBezier for it.

```
ccBezierConfig bezier;
        bezier.controlPoint_1 = ccp(monster.position.x, actualY);
        bezier.controlPoint_2 = ccp(monster.position.x, actualY+40);
        bezier.endPosition = ccp(monster.position.x,actualY);
        CCBezierTo *bezierAction = [CCBezierTo actionWithDuration:1 bezier:bezier];




        id action = [CCSpawn actions:actionMove,bezierAction,nil];

        id seq = [CCSequence actions:
                  action,
                  actionMoveDone,
                  nil];

        [monster runAction:seq];
```

The monsters zigzag only one time, How can i doing this constantly?

Sorry for my bad english.

Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

[monster runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:seq]];

That would just repeat the sequence you created forever. Is that what you wanted?
Alternatively you could use CCRepeat if you wanted it to just do the action a few times then stop.

Also, I think your English was fine.

Comment: i tried this answer before ask the question, but it is working only one time.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I see is that even if you get the bezier action to repeat, it's going to repeat the same bezier curve each time.  Given that you're using CCBezerTo it will move from the position the sprite has when the action commences to the position within the bezier config.

You need to update the bezier config each time it completes so that the config represents a movement from the sprite position (at the end of the previous bezier) to where you want it to zig or zag to.

Rather than use CCRepeatForever, I'd be inclined to have a CCBlockAction as the last action in the sequence.  Within that action, make a call back to the routine that sets everything up.

Essentially, you're setting up a recursive action that, when it completes, it tells itself to start again, but by this time the sprite is in a new position so visually you will get what you want.

You will of course need some sort of control in there to allow you to cause the action to complete at some point.